# Taking a bit-by-bit image of an Android Filesystem

Tags: java, android, adb, computer-forensics

Is it possible to take a perfect copy of the android file system. Note I am not talking about the SD card here, as that is removable and traditional techniques can be used. I am talking about the Android file system itself, which would have to be connected to a PC via USB.

I presume the device would have to be rooted, as I'm failre sure Google do now allow full exposure of the OS OOB.

Would I have to develop an application to run on the device, farm the data, and then write a further desktop application to retrieve all the information, or is it possible to just do the equivalent of DD programatically?

Any language will do as a POC, but the end product will probably be done in JAVA.

Comment: you could also take it from the emulator.

Comment: Or download a custom ROM, already prepared

Comment: Can't install a custom ROM, it's got to be in a forensic like environment.

Answer (score 0):

For a properly rooted device you could just do `adb pull` for every partition you want one by one:

```
adb pull /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata userdata.bin
```

The block device path is specific to the SoC chipset (Qualcomm in my example)

Comment: Ideally I would need to write a function myself

Comment: You did not know where to start from. I told you about one possible way to achieve your goal. It's up to you to implement it in whatever language you want. So what's stopping you now?